# Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator`1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, icollection

I have the following code (please note that this is stripped down to the relevant part, the actual query is a lot more complex):

```
public IQueryable<Menu> GetMenus(DateTime lastUpdate) {
    ...
    result = GetAll().Where(m => lastUpdate < m.LastModified)
                     .ForEach(m => m.Descriptions = m.Descriptions
                                                     .Where(d => lastUpdate < d.LastModified));
    ...
enter code here
```

This is an function within an update service routine for an App to get any menu, which either itself or any of its descriptions has changed since the update service was last called.

**Clarification: The function needs to return every Menu, which has changed since the last call. Additionally, it needs to return every changed Description of every changed Menu. but it must leave out the unchanged Descriptions.**

**As an Example:**

```
Menu menuA = new Menu() {
    LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 24),
    Descriptions = new List<Description>() {
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 24) },
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 01) }
    }
};
Menu menuB = new Menu() {
    LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 20),
    Descriptions = new List<Description>() {
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 01) }
    }
};
```

**Now, when I call the update function with *new DateTime(2014, 12, 15)*, this is the structure it needs to return:**

```
List<Menu>: {
    menuA: {
        LastModified: DateTime(2014, 12, 24),
        Descriptions: List<Description> {
            Description: {
                LastModified: DateTime(2014, 12, 24),
            }
        }
    },
    menuB: {
        LastModified: DateTime(2014, 12, 20),
        Descriptions: List<Description> {}
    }
}
```

**With *ForEach()* looking like this:**

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action) {
        ... // Parameter check
        foreach (T item in source) {
            action(item);
        }
        return source;
    }
```

Menu and Description were automatically created by entity framework like this:

```
public partial class Menu {
    ...
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class Description {
    ...
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately the `Where` function returns an `IEnumerabley<Description>`, which cannot be cast internally to the `ICollection<Description>` defined by entity framework.

When I try to cast it myself like this I get the runtime error within the title:

```
m => m.Descriptions = (ICollection<Description>)m.Descriptions.Where(...)
```

Now, I do understand as to why this error is thrown. The Description's `Where` expression has not yet been evaluated, so what is supposed to being cast to `ICollection<Description>` is not an `IEnumerable<Description>` yet, but a WhereEnumerableIterator. Right now I'm casting the `Where` expression to a list, which gets evaluated immediately and then cast to `ICollection<Description>`.

```
m => m.Descriptions = (ICollection<Description>)m.Descriptions.Where(...).ToList()
```

However, this is merely a workaround killing the benefits of the LINQ expression and besides, plain ugly. I could write an extension method `WhereCollection<T>(...)` calling `Where<T>` and returning an `ICollection<T>` but that wouldn't change much, I'd have to do the cast internally which either results in the same error or calls `ToList()` internally.

Is there an elegant solution to this problem, without forcing the `Where` expression to evaluate before the LINQ statement gets evaluated?

Comment: What is your `ForEach` method, which apparently returns something?

Comment: Makes sense. Do you know whether the `Menu.Descriptions` property is lazy loaded by Entity Framework?

Comment: If I got it correctly, the virtual keyword declares lazy loading, so yes, the `Menu.Descriptions` are lazy loaded.

Answer (score 1):

"This is an function within an update service routine for an App to get any menu, which either **itself or any of its descriptions** has changed since the update service was last called."

So... wouldn't you have a slightly complex `Where` clause in this case instead of all that?

```
result = GetAll()
         .Where(m => lastUpdate < m.LastModified || 
                m.Descriptions.Any(d => lastUpdate < d.LastModified);
```

Your problem statement basically described the LINQ query. ;)

Comment: Form the query logic i think that the OP wants to remove unchanged descriptions.

Comment: That's not the way I read his problem statement - OP is quite clear on what the function is supposed to do but the code he has provided clearly does not do that. Mostly because you can't call `ForEach()` on `IEnumerable<T>` result of `Where()`.

Comment: Looks like I haven't been clear enough, my bad. I've updated my question. Ben Robinson is indeed right. And yes, you **can** call a `ForEach()` on an `IEnumerable<T>` if you've written an extension method, which I did. I simply had left it out because it was not part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an elegant solution to this problem, without forcing the Where expression to evaluate before the LINQ statement gets evaluated?

The `ForEach` extension makes it not elegant and is likely the problem. There is a reason `ForEach` is not included in Linq. Linq uses functional "pure" methods but `ForEach` uses side effects.

Your `GetMenus` Method returns `IQueryable<Menu>`. Thus if your `GetAll()` also returns an  `IQueryable<>`, then your `ForEach` is a performance problem. The reason is, when you call Linq methods on `IQueryable<>` like `dc.Customers.Where(c => c.Age >= 18)`, when the Linq statement is converted into an SQL `WHERE`, so only some customers are loaded form the database. If you would write `dc.Customers.ForEach(c => ...)` and if `ForEach` would accept `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable` (as in your case), then you are querying in-memory from that point on and not on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Menu` object you need is different then the records you are reading from the database (it will be missing some `Description` objects), you need to create new `Menu` objects:

Here is the full working version (direct from LinqPad)

```
void Main()
{
    GetMenus(new DateTime(2014,12,15)).Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<Menu> GetMenus(DateTime lastUpdate)
{
    var result = from m in GetAll()
                where lastUpdate < m.LastModified
                select new Menu
                {
                    LastModified = m.LastModified,
                    Descriptions = m.Descriptions.Where(d =>lastUpdate < d.LastModified ).ToList()
                };
                
    return result;
}

IEnumerable<Menu> GetAll() 
{
    Menu menuA = new Menu() {
    LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 24),
    Descriptions = new List<Description>() {
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 24) },
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 01) }
    }
};
Menu menuB = new Menu() {
    LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 20),
    Descriptions = new List<Description>() {
        new Description() { LastModified = new DateTime(2014, 12, 01) }
    }
};

    return new List<Menu>{menuA, menuB};
}


public partial class Menu {

    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
}

public partial class Description
{
    public System.DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }
}
```

I had to convert the `IQueryable`s to `IEnumerables` since I didn't have your database, but I also did a similar version that did read from a database and it worked there as well.